# discord.py search and return url of first hit

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, wikipedia

I want to be able to make a bot so I can f.eks. search on the wiki.
The command would be:

!wiki (Article)
And it would send you the URL to that website.
Here is an example of how I thought it would be possible

```
@client.command()
async def wiki(ctx, search):
    client.search(search + "Wikipedia")
    await ctx.send(first_hit)
```

Comment: Are you trying to search in discord or on wikipedia?

Comment: i want a discord bot to send the url to a wiki article by searching in discord

Comment: So you are not searching in discord

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
async def wiki(ctx, *args):
    term = args.replace(" ", "+")
    await ctx.send("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=",term)
```

This would be the link to the search. In the example it just sends the search query link. Using the `urllib.request` (rq) module,
you can then get this site with rq.urlopen(link), parse the html and select the first link and then send it to the user.